# Using Rejection Method to Sample with a given density function?

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability, probability-density

I'm attempting to sample 1000 numbers from a distribution with a given density which is f(x) = (1/3)* X^2 between -1 < x < 2. So far I have this, however given the histogram, it is clearly wrong but I think I'm going in the right direction. Any help as to how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
X=rand(0,1000); Y=rand(1,10000);
a=-1;
b=2;
c=2;
f = (1/3).*X.^2; 

for i = 1:length(X)
while(Y(i) > f )
    U = rand; V = rand;
    X(i) = a+(b-a)*U;
    Y(i) = c*V;
end

end
hist(X);
X
```

Comment: Is it maybe a bug? First line should maybe be `X=rand(1,1000);`?

Comment: @mpaskov I think that worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, max value of `f` is reached at 2, and is equal to 4/3. If you set your `c` to 4/3, your sampling would be more efficient

Answer (score -1):

Drawing samples from an arbitrary distribution is actually quite simple. You only have to do two things: 1) find the CDF (by integrating the PDF), and 2) find the inverse of the CDF. Then you just draw samples from a uniform distribution (using rand()) and map that value onto the inverse of the CDF. In your case you get

y = rand(1e6, 1);
x = nthroot((9*c - 1), 3);
hist(x, 1000)

Comment: Sorry, meant to say

Comment: y = rand(1e6, 1);
x = nthroot((9*y - 1), 3);
hist(x, 1000)

Comment: You've answered related but not directly asked question. THere is NO rejection used in your code.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "rejection"?

Comment: I wasn't proposing rejection sampling. Every sample  nthroot((9*rand - 1), 3) will be from the distribution (1/3)*x^2, -1<x<2.

Comment: That's correct. You're using inverse CDF method. But question was "Using Rejection Method ...", so you've answered related, but different question.